# AngularJs - cannot cancel route change without disabling "expand menu"

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

**The Picture:**
[image]

**The Html:**

```
// the ng-class allow the expansion of menu            
  <li class="{{menuItem.isActive}}" data-ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menuItems" data-ng-class="{'': vm.expandedItem !== menuItem, 'expanded': vm.expandedItem === menuItem}" data-ng-click="vm.expandNav(menuItem, menuItem.url)"  style="cursor: pointer;">

  // click to go to next route
   <a href="{{menuItem.url}}">                     
      <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menuItem.name}}</span>
        <b data-ng-if="menuItem.subMenu.length > 0 ">
          <em class="fa" data-ng-class="{'fa fa-expand-o': vm.expandedItem !== menuItem, 'fa fa-collapse-o': vm.expandedItem === menuItem}">
                    </em>
                </b>
            </a>
```

**The Expand Menu Code:**

```
    vm.expandNav = function (item, url) {
        if (url == '') {
            if (item !== vm.expandedItem) {
                vm.expandedItem = item;
            } else {
                vm.expandedItem = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

**Some Data:**

```
    vm.menuItems = [
          { name: "Dashboard", url: "/", icon: "fa-home", isActive: "active" },
          { name: "Inbox", url: "/inserts/inbox", icon: "fa-inbox" },
          { name: "Graphs", url: "#", icon: "fa-bar-chart-o",
              subMenu:
                  [
                      { name: "Flot Charts", url: "/inserts/flot" },
                      { name: "Morris Charts", url: "/inserts/morris" },
                      { name: "Inline Charts", url: "/inserts/inline-charts" }
                  ]
          }
```

**Route Provider "otherwise" doing it:**

```
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '/app/html/inserts/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        });
```

**Scenario [Problem:]**

I am on the inbox page, I click on the graphs menu and before clicking a choice, my view reverts back to the default dashboard page.

I tried to preventDefault with $locationChangeStart but that prevents the menu from expanding so I can see the sub menus.

What I want: To remain on whatever page I clicked (in this case the Inbox page), click on any other menu item that has submenus (eg Graphs) and not have my view move off from the Inbox view it was currently on.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

**The correct code in the controller:**

```
    vm.expandNav = function (item, url) {
        if (url === '#') {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (item !== vm.expandedItem) {
                vm.expandedItem = item;
            } else {
                vm.expandedItem = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

**The correct html:**

```
    <ul>
        <li class="{{menuItem.isActive}}" data-ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menuItems" data-ng-class="{'': vm.expandedItem !== menuItem, 'expanded': vm.expandedItem === menuItem}" data-ng-click="vm.expandNav(menuItem, menuItem.url)" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <a ng-href="{{menuItem.url}}">
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menuItem.name}}</span>
                <b data-ng-if="menuItem.subMenu.length > 0 ">
                    <em class="fa" data-ng-class="{'fa fa-expand-o': vm.expandedItem !== menuItem, 'fa fa-collapse-o': vm.expandedItem === menuItem}">
                    </em>
                </b>
            </a>
            <ul data-ng-class="{'expanded': vm.expandedItem !== menuItem, 'expanded expandMe': vm.expandedItem === menuItem}" data-ng-click="vm.expandNav(menuItem, menuItem.url)">
                <li data-ng-repeat="subMenu in menuItem.subMenu">
                    <a ng-href="{{subMenu.url}}" style="cursor: pointer;">{{subMenu.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to cancelBubble instead of preventDefault, but it may be preferable to move the expand element out of the anchor to avoid directive/event conflicts altogether. Would that be possible?

Comment: I haven't a blessed clue what you are proposing. I thought my situation was well explained.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems. First, it looks like your checking for the wrong url value in `vm.expandNav`. You're checking if url is empty but your graph url is set to `'#'` Second, you need to prevent the default after that check succeeds.

```
vm.expandNav = function (item, url) {
  if (url === '#') {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (item !== vm.expandedItem) {
      vm.expandedItem = item;
    } else {
      vm.expandedItem = null;
    }
  }
};
```

The `event.preventDefault()` tells the child `a` tag that it shouldn't visit its `href`. Without that, your click event is going to run but the click will continue to cascade down and will send your browser to `http://<domain>/#`. That's what's happening now and why your `otherwise` is picking it up and sending you to your default dashboard.

Also, when you're using interpolation to populate an `href` you should use `ng-href` instead:

```
<a ng-href="{{menuItem.url}}">
```